# How to check if a module/library/package is part of the python standard library?

Tags: python, module, package, native

I have installed sooo many libraries/modules/packages with pip and now I cannot differentiate which is native to the python standard library and which is not. This causes problem when my code works on my machine but it doesn't work anywhere else.

**How can I check if a module/library/package that I import in my code is from the python stdlib?**

Assume that the checking is done on the machine with all the external libraries/modules/packages, otherwise I could simply do a try-except import on the other machine that doesn't have them.

For example, I am sure these imports work on my machine, but when it's on a machine with only a plain Python install, it breaks:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
import PIL
import gensim
```

Comment: You could start here I guess: http://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html

Comment: Work with virtualenv. It's built specifically to avoid these problems.

Comment: It's not an answer as such, but if you followed [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) it would be easier to see which `import`s are third-party

Comment: 'native python' usually refers to 'pure python', e.g. not using any C or other non-Python language extensions. You are instead talking about the standard library vs. external dependencies.

Comment: ah, @martijnpieters, thanks for the note on 'native python'. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd have to check all modules that have been imported to see if any of these are located outside of the standard library.

The following script is *not* bulletproof but should give you a starting point:

```
import sys
import os

external = set()
exempt = set()
paths = (os.path.abspath(p) for p in sys.path)
stdlib = {p for p in paths
          if p.startswith((sys.prefix, sys.real_prefix)) 
          and 'site-packages' not in p}
for name, module in sorted(sys.modules.items()):
    if not module or name in sys.builtin_module_names or not hasattr(module, '__file__'):
        # an import sentinel, built-in module or not a real module, really
        exempt.add(name)
        continue

    fname = module.__file__
    if fname.endswith(('__init__.py', '__init__.pyc', '__init__.pyo')):
        fname = os.path.dirname(fname)

    if os.path.dirname(fname) in stdlib:
        # stdlib path, skip
        exempt.add(name)
        continue

    parts = name.split('.')
    for i, part in enumerate(parts):
        partial = '.'.join(parts[:i] + [part])
        if partial in external or partial in exempt:
            # already listed or exempted
            break
        if partial in sys.modules and sys.modules[partial]:
            # just list the parent name and be done with it
            external.add(partial)
            break

for name in external:
    print name, sys.modules[name].__file__
```

Put this is a new module, import it *after* all imports in your script, and it'll print all modules that it thinks are *not* part of the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

The standard library is defined in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/) of python. You can just search there, or put the module names into a list and check programmatically with that.

Alternatively, in python3.4 there's a new [isolated mode](http://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-isolated-mode) that allows to ignore a certain number of user-defined library paths. In previous versions of python you can use `-s` to ignore the per-user environment and `-E` to ignore the system defined variables.

In python2 a very simple way to check if a module is part of the standard library is to clear the `sys.path`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path = []
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> import traceback
>>> import os
>>> import re
```

However this doesn't work in python3.3+:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path = []
>>> import traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'traceback'
[...]
```

This is because starting with python3.3 the import machinery was changed, and importing the standard library uses the same mechanism as importing any other module (see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#importlib)).

In python3.3 the only way to make sure that only stdlib's imports succeed is to add only the standard library path to `sys.path`, for example:

```
>>> import os, sys, traceback
>>> lib_path = os.path.dirname(traceback.__file__)
>>> sys.path = [lib_path]
>>> import traceback
>>> import re
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I used the `traceback` module to get the library path, since this should work on any system.

For the built-in modules, which are a *subset* of the stdlib modules, you can check [`sys.builtin_module_names`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names)

Comment: But this is not about stdlib vs. third-party, it's non-pure third-party vs. pure Python third-party.

Comment: @tripleee: I don't agree; I think the OP is mixing terms here. `bs4` is pure Python, while PIL is certainly not. Neither won't be installed on a new machine.

Comment: @triplee, it's about stdlib vs third-party. because third-party libs are not installed on my collaborators' machine, they are pissing them off badly... leaving me with questions like "how can you just do X in two lines?" ... lolz

Answer (score 2):

@Bakuriu's answer was very useful to me. The only problem I experienced is if you want to check if a particular module is stdlib however is has been imported already. In that case, `sys.modules` will only have an entry for it so even if `sys.path` is stripped, the import will succeed:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: import virtualenv

In [3]: sys.path = []

In [4]: try:
    __import__('virtualenv')
except ImportError:
    print(False)
else:
    print(True)
   ...:
True
```

vs

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path = []

In [3]: try:
    __import__('virtualenv')
except ImportError:
    print(False)
else:
    print(True)
   ...:
False
```

I whipped out the following solution which seems to work in both Python2 and Python3:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager
from importlib import import_module


@contextmanager
def ignore_site_packages_paths():
    paths = sys.path
    # remove all third-party paths
    # so that only stdlib imports will succeed
    sys.path = list(filter(
        None,
        filter(lambda i: 'site-packages' not in i, sys.path)
    ))
    yield
    sys.path = paths


def is_std_lib(module):
    if module in sys.builtin_module_names:
        return True

    with ignore_site_packages_paths():
        imported_module = sys.modules.pop(module, None)
        try:
            import_module(module)
        except ImportError:
            return False
        else:
            return True
        finally:
            if imported_module:
                sys.modules[module] = imported_module
```

You can keep track of the source code [here](https://github.com/miki725/importanize/blob/master/importanize/utils.py)