# Creating Anaconda Environment from YML File Choking on Common Packages - os, pip, pandas

Tags: pip, anaconda, package, installation, environment

Why is anaconda choking on common packages, in creating an envionment from a YML file? Anaconda COMES with these packages pre-installed in root (or so I thought?)

YML file:

```
---
name: rasterenv
channels:
        - conda-forge

dependencies:
        - gdal>=2.2.3
        - rasterio
        - cython
        - jupyter
        - matplotlib
        - numpy
        - pyproj
        - shapely
        - rasterio
        - pandas
        - geopandas
        - os
        - matplotlib
        - seaborn
        - fiona
        - OSMnx
        - pip:
            - pygeotools
            - pygeoprocessing
```

Trying to build file with: `conda env create -f path/to/file`

If I create an enviornment with JUST uncommon packages like rasterio, it appears to work. BUT, I want an environment with all! What gives here?

Error is:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - os
```

If I remove `os` from the list, the error then becomes:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - matplotlib
```

Comment: [`os` is part of Python's _standard library_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), it should always be available, no need to specify it as a dependency.

Comment: Yeah, definitely remove `os` from the dependencies. Also, did you manually create that file? `rasterio` and `matplotlib` are in that list twice.

Comment: @orangeInk how do I know what packages need to be specified, and which are available? Is anything beyond the standard library available (e.g. pandas)? If you can add an answer vs a comment then I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sinoroc pointed out in the comments, `os` is part of Python standard library and should not be listed as a dependency. (When you do define it as a dependency, Python is going to look for a package called `os` on all available repositories [PyPI or anaconda.org in this case] and won't find it.)

You can see which packages are part of the standard library by checking the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/
(Also there have been a few questions on SO on how to find out if a particular package is part of the std lib, e.g. [How to check if a module/library/package is part of the python standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195382/how-to-check-if-a-module-library-package-is-part-of-the-python-standard-library)) When you create a new environment the packages from the std lib are the only ones which are available by default. Anything else needs to be installed.

Additionally there are two packages in your yaml file that are listed twice (`rasterio` and `matplotlib`) which makes me think that you manually created that file. You can generate a conda environment file by activating an environment and running `conda env export > environment.yml` which will create a file called `environment.yml` with all required dependencies.